# Evaluating a mathematical expression in a string form

Tags: algorithm, stack

This is a standard interview question, evaluate a mathematical expression given in the form of a string.

So provided, `'3+3-6*2'`
The answer should be `-6`

Now if the expressions only support four operations `+,-,*,/`
Then is there a simple way to do it using a stack.

I've solved it by converting the infix notation to postfix and then solving it using a stack - but I'm looking for a different approach that supports only these four operations. This is my solution,

```python
def evaluate(self, s: str) -> int:
    expr = [i for i in re.split(r'(\d+|\W+)', s) if i]
    rpn = self.convertToPostfix(expr)
    return self.evalPostfix(rpn)

def convertToPostfix(self, infix: list) -> list:
    stack = collections.deque()
    result = []
    for item in infix:
        if item.isdigit():
            result.append(item)
        else:
            while len(stack) > 0 and self.has_higher_precedence(stack[-1], item):
                result.append(stack[-1])
                stack.pop()
            stack.append(item)
    while len(stack) > 0:
        result.append(stack.pop())
    return result

def has_higher_precedence(self, a: str, b: str) -> bool:
    if a == '/' and b == '*' or b == '+' or b == '-':
        return True
    if a == '*' and b == '+' or '-':
        return True
    if a == '+' and b == '-':
        return True
    return False

def evalPostfix(self, p: list) -> int:
    stack = collections.deque()
    for item in p:
        if item.isdigit():
            stack.append(int(item))
        elif item[1:].isdigit():
            stack.append(int(item))
        else:
            curr = stack.pop()
            prev = stack.pop()
            if item == '+':
                total = prev + curr
            elif item == '-':
                total = prev - curr
            elif item == '*':
                total = prev * curr
            else:
                total = prev / curr
            stack.append(total)
    return stack.pop()
```

Also I'm aware that this can be solved by designing a recursive lexical parser but that's beyond the scope of this question.

**So my question is, is there a simple way to do this in O(n) time using a stack if there are only four operators**

Comment: The [Shunting-yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) is the standard way to solve this problem. There are no parentheses in your equations, so you could leave that part of the algorithm out if you want to simplify.

Comment: @JimMischel I think my code is basically an implementation of the shunting yard algorithm.

Comment: Without parentheses you don't even need a stack, finite memory is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the Shunting-yard algorithm to parse and evaluate in a single pass. There is no need for the intermediate step of converting to postfix. Restricting the problem to just the four standard mathematical operators with no parentheses doesn't change the basic approach.

Here's the standard Shunting-yard algorithm, from the linked article. I've added line numbers for reference below:

```
 1: while there are tokens to be read:
 2: read a token.
 3: if the token is a number, then push it to the output queue.
 4: if the token is an operator, then:
 5:     while (there is an operator at the top of the operator stack with
 6:         greater precedence) or (the operator at the top of the operator stack has
 7:                        equal precedence and
 8:                        the operator is left associative) and
 9:                      (the operator at the top of the stack is not a left bracket):
10:             pop operators from the operator stack, onto the output queue.
11:     push the read operator onto the operator stack.
12: if the token is a left bracket (i.e. "("), then:
13:     push it onto the operator stack.
14: if the token is a right bracket (i.e. ")"), then:
15:     while the operator at the top of the operator stack is not a left bracket:
16:         pop operators from the operator stack onto the output queue.
17:     pop the left bracket from the stack.
        /* if the stack runs out without finding a left bracket, then there are
18:     mismatched parentheses. */
19: if there are no more tokens to read:
20:     while there are still operator tokens on the stack:
21:         /* if the operator token on the top of the stack is a bracket, then
22:         there are mismatched parentheses. */
23:         pop the operator onto the output queue.
24: exit.
```

The modifications involve replacing the output queue with an operand stack: a stack of integers. So, for example, on line 3 instead of pushing the number to the output queue, you push the number onto the operand stack. This will of course require you to convert the character to an integer.

Then, on line 10 where you pop operators from the operator stack and push to the output queue, you instead:

1. Pop an operator
2. Pop two operands from the operand stack
3. Perform the operation
4. Push the result back onto the operand stack

You replace lines 16 and 23 with the same kind of logic.

If at any time when you're evaluating, there are not enough operands on the operand stack, then you have mismatched operators: something like 2+3+- (unless you decide to support unary + and unary -), or  2*/3.

When you've reached line 24, the operator stack is empty and the operand stack should contain a single value: the final result. If is more than one item on the operand stack, then you have too many operands (shouldn't happen).

So replace line 24 with a pop from the operand stack, and you can return that as the result.

The Shunting-yard is actually a very simplified version of the "recursive lexical parser" that you mentioned. But rather than building stack frames through recursion, it manipulates the stacks directly.

Modifying your code to do this shouldn't be too difficult. Below is a modified version of your `convertToPostfix` function, called `evaluateInfix`, that does it all in a single pass. Note that I'm not a Python programmer, so I won't guarantee the code to work flawlessly, but it should give you the idea:

```
def evaluateInfix(self, infix: list) -> int:
    operatorStack = collections.deque()
    operandStack = collections.deque()
    result = []
    for item in infix:
        if item.isdigit():
            val = convertDigitToNumber(item)  // however that's done
            // push to operand stack
            operandStack.append(val)
        else:
            while len(operatorStack) > 0 and self.has_higher_precedence(operatorStack[-1], item):
                // pop two operands from stack, evaluate, and push result
                // call this "pop and eval"
                op2 = operandStack[-1]
                operandStack.pop()
                op1 = operandStack[-1]
                operandStack.pop()
                operator = operatorStack[-1]
                operatorStack.pop()
                val = evaluate(operator, op1, op2) // this function evaluates op1 <operator> op2

                // push result back onto operand stack
                operandStack.append(val)
            operatorStack.append(item)
    while len(operatorStack) > 0:
        // insert "pop and eval" code here
    // at this point there should be a single value on the operand stack
    return operandStack[-1]
```

The `evaluate` function takes an operator and two operands, does the operation, and returns the result. So given `('+', 3, 5)`, it would compute `3+5`, and return `8`.

The idea here is that whenever you evaluate, you're taking two operands and a single operator.

Test case: `3+5*2`.

```
       operand    operator
char    stack      stack
--------------------------
  3     [3]       []
  +     [3]       [+]
  5     [3,5]     [+]
  *     [3,5]     [+,*]
  2     [3,5,2]   [+,*]
 <end>
 at this point, we're at the end of the string.
 Pop 2 and 5 from the operand stack, pop * from the operator stack,
 and evaluate
        [3,10]    [+]
 pop and eval again
        [13]      []
 operator stack is empty. Pop result from operand stack and return.
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this, it might help if you could write some code here.

Comment: @MelissaStewart: See my updated answer, with code. It's really just a simple combining of your convert and evaluate functions.

Comment: that really helped, especially the last walkthrough. I've posted working python code for purely completion sake.

Answer (score 2):

You could store the string as a list of characters and then run through it linearly 2 times, first calculating for multiplication/division then addition/subtraction.

i.e. In the first iteration have

```
1+10/2 -> 1 + 5
```

then have

```
1 + 5 -> 6
```

This could also easily be implemented with a stack, to which you add the numbers with the + or - sign. When you are adding to the stack and realize you have reached a `/` or `*` sign, you pop the previous element, multiply or divide it by the current number, and push it back. Finally, you find the sum of all the elements in a stack.

Even further, you can make the observation that in the previous example, the only element of the stack being used was one directly preceding the answer. This suggests that you can store the previous element while maintaining a sum and if you reach a `*` or `/` sign, then subtracting the previous element from the sum and adding the updated element. This method effectively solves the problem in one O(n) scan with O(1) extra storage, making it possibly the optimal solution for this problem.

Comment: I don't think this algorithm takes the natural order of the operators into consideration.

Comment: This is better than shunting-yard (doesn't require a stack) but doesn't support parentheses. Assuming parentheses are not needed, this is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

For completion sake, posting @Jim Mischel solution as working Python 3 code.

```
import re


class Solution:
    def evalExpression(self, s):
        operator_stack, operand_stack = [], []
        tokens = [i for i in re.split(r'(\d+|\W+)', s) if i]
        for token in tokens:
            if token.isdigit():
                operand_stack.append(int(token))
            else:
                while len(operator_stack) > 0 and self.has_higher_precedence(operator_stack[-1], token):
                    val = self.evaluate(operand_stack.pop(), operator_stack.pop(), operand_stack.pop())
                    operand_stack.append(val)
                operator_stack.append(token)
        while len(operator_stack) > 0:
            val = self.evaluate(operand_stack.pop(), operator_stack.pop(), operand_stack.pop())
            operand_stack.append(val)
        return operand_stack[-1]

    def has_higher_precedence(self, opr1, opr2):
        if opr1 == '/' or opr1 == '*' and opr2 == '+' or opr2 == '-':
            return True
        return False

    def evaluate(self, a, b, c):
        if b == '/':
            return c/a
        elif b == '*':
            return c*a
        elif b == '-':
            return c-a
        else:
            return c+a


if __name__ == '__main__':
    solution = Solution()
    print(solution.evalExpression('3+3-6*2'))
```